# require function inside or outside of prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

### I often use prototypes such as these:

requiring the same or similar functions over and over in different files.
Would it be better to require `Element` inside the scope or outside the scope as done so below?

I guess it's should be outside, otherwise I will be creating lots of copies of Element all over my code, **No?**

```
var Element = require("./Element.js")
var _ = function(){
    this.element = new Element();
    this.stuff;
}
_.prototype.setStuff = function(stuff){
    this.stuff = stuff
}
_.prototype.doStuff = function(){
    this.stuff();
}

module.exports = _;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a node.js module, there are several considerations here:

1. `require()` is synchronous.  Thus you don't ever want to use it inside of live server requests because that blocks the scalability of your server.  You will generally want to use `require()` once when a module is initialized and your server is being initialized.
2. Variables declared within a node.js module are scoped only to the module.   Technically the module scope is inside a module function so any variables declared there are already local variables and thus don't need any extra scope protection.
3. Modules are cached.  So, it is very fast if you do `require()` multiple times on the same path.  After the first time when the module is actually loaded and initialized, all subsequent calls just return the same cached module handle.  So, don't try to mess with the structure of your code to reduce the number of places you call `require()`.  Write clean code and if that necessitates calling `require()` a few times on the same module, that's no big deal.

> requiring the same or similar functions over and over in different
>   files. Would it be better to require Element inside the scope or
>   outside the scope as done so below?

You usually want to put `require()` statements at the highest level in your node.js modules because you want to initialize them once when the module is first initialized and you want to share that module handle with all the code in the module.  If your code is complex enough that you feel like calling `require()` for the same module in several different places to keep your code more partitioned, then you probably should be breaking your code into separate modules anyway and let each module `require()` in whatever it needs itself.

> I guess it's should be outside, otherwise I will be creating lots of
>   copies of Element all over my code,

Outside at the highest scope in your module.  There's really little reason not to just load the module once and share the module handle with all the code in the module that might want to use it.

---

There are a few special cases where you might want to dynamically load modules only in some specific conditions at run-time only when a module is needed.  This is rare and has performance consequences when doing so because of the synchronous nature of loading modules so it is rarely done.  So, I didn't want to be absolute in my earlier recommendation, but also wanted to explain that loading something only on-demand is rare and has consequences.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @jfriend00

Comment: @jfriend00 So the Op's code is not dynamically loading modules, right? He is putting the `require()` at the highest level of the module, right? so is his pattern good? or is he using require  multiple times if he does something like  `var inst =  new _.element()`. I'm not sure if his pattern is good. what  do you think?

Comment: @jackblank - As the OP's code is displayed now, it is good. They were asking if they should change it.

Answer (score 0):

Here Element should be defined inside the _ function scope unless it is defined inside a IIFE.
If it is defined inside IIFE then there won't be any issue else Element will be exposed into window scope and using console we can override the Element function.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Because of the use of `require()`, I'm assuming this code is inside a `node.js` module and thus you don't need an IIFE to limit the scope of variables defined at the top level as they are already scoped to just the module.  And, there is no `window scope` in node.js.